# How can I prevent C# and Selenium from exiting code 0

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, exit-code

```
while (1 == 1)
{
    int questions = 0;
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    
    try
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[1]"));

        questions++;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    try
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[2]"));

        questions++;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    try
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[3]"));

        questions++;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    try
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[4]"));

        questions++;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (questions == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (questions == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("1", "1");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[1]")).Click();
    }
    else if (questions == 2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("2", "2");
        String[] av2 = { "//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[1]",
            "//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[2]"};
        Random random = new Random();
        int a = random.Next(av2.Length);
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(av2[a])).Click();
    }
    else if (questions == 3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("3", "3");
        String[] av3 =
        {
            "//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[1]",
            "//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[2]",
            "//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[3]"
        };
        Random random = new Random();
        int a = random.Next(av3.Length);
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(av3[a])).Click();
    }
    else if (questions == 4)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("4", "4");
        String[] av4 =
        {
            "//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[1]",
            "//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[2]",
            "//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[3]",
            "//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[4]"
        };
        Random random = new Random();
        int a = random.Next(av4.Length);
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(av4[a])).Click();
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine(questions + " <");
}
```

I'm not experienced at all, and don't know why this class keeps exiting with code 0. I've tried multiple things, but none worked. So, what I am trying to have it do is have this piece of C# code check for an xpath with selenium every .5 seconds. but as it is right now, it exits with exit code 0. How can i fix this?

Comment: When there is an error (exception) you exit (return) your code without any message. At least print the exception message

Comment: Isn't it like in old C# - where you need to set your application as "int main" and then return the "int" code you want?

Comment: A side note, `Random random = new Random();` set the scope of this at the top, not local.

Comment: Just FYI, it's generally accepted that `while(true)` is more readable/intentional.

Comment: You should remove the `return` statement if you don't want the loop to exit in the `catch` blocks. Or,  if you want to exit with a non-0 value, you can calll `Environment.Exit(someExitCode)` (or `return someExitCode;` if this is in the `Main` method and it's defined to return an `int`). It's not really clear what you want to do if there's an exception.

Answer (score 0):

`return` statement, if placed in the `Main` function, stops execution of the program. Move your code to function, and add some logic to prevent console application from closing

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoYourThings();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close application...");
            Console.ReadKey(); // application hangs here until user clicks any button, 
            // so you have time to examine console window
        }

        static void DoYourThings()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try 
                {
                    // some code
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message); // output exception message
                    return; // exits DoYourThings function
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't that `return` statement defeat the purpose of the `while` loop?

Comment: OP had it in catch blocks, I omitted that part of code just to illustrate its functionality. Included it for clarification, thanks.

Comment: I think that is the root of the problem though...the `catch` block is there because `FindElement` will throw an exception if the specified element isn't found and I *think* he wants to just ignore those exceptions. If that's the case, then there shouldn't be a `return` at all. But I could be wrong..?

Comment: My assumption is that OP is familiar with selenium, but not with C#, so it is more debugging question (name also tells that), than a selenium one

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to select a random item from several XPaths (if found) and click it. The problem is that instead of ignoring exceptions (by not doing anything) you're calling `return;`, which will exit the method.

Instead, you can just remove the `return` statement from inside your `catch` blocks, and that should resolve your issue.

Additionally, you seem to have a lot of repeated code which can be simplified if we store some of the results in lists and then loop over those lists (and choose a random element from a list). Also, you only need to initialize the instance of `Random` once.

For example:

```
// Only initialize random one time
var random = new Random();

// Store our XPaths in a list so we can loop over them
var buttonXPaths = new List<string>
{
    $"//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[1]",
    $"//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[2]",
    $"//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[3]",
    $"//*[@id='root']/div/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/button[4]",
};
        
// Endless loop
while (true)
{
    // Sleep for half a second
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    // Create a list to hold any WebElements we find
    var elements = new List<WebElement>();

    // For each XPath, try to find the element and add it to our list
    foreach (var buttonXPath in buttonXPaths)
    {
        try
        {
            elements.Add(driver.FindElement(buttonXPath));
        }
        catch
        {
            // Ignore any exceptions. The next line isn't necessary, but I
            // included it so you can see the syntax for explicitly skipping 
            // a loop iteration and starting it over again (you were using 'return')
            continue;
        }
    }

    // If we found any elements. This is the same as: if (elements.Count > 0)
    if (elements.Any())
    {
        // Display the number of elements found in a message box
        MessageBox.Show(elements.Count.ToString(), elements.Count.ToString());

        // Choose a random element from our list
        WebElement randomElement = elements[random.Next(elements.Count)];

        // Click it
        randomElement.Click();

        // This was in your code, not sure why
        Console.WriteLine($"{elements.Count} <");
    }
}
```